# Is there a way to pass a variable from jquery to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
<button type="button" class="metric">Metric</button>
<button type="button" class="imperial">Imperial</button>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $( '.metric' ).click(function(){
        count = 0;
    });
    $( '.imperial' ).click(function(){
        count = 1;  
    });
});
console.log(count);     
</script>
```

I am currently getting undefinded from my console. Is there a way to get the variable from jquery to vannila javascript?

Comment: jQuery **is** regular Javascript. Where is your `console.log` in your code? Note, that unless you defined variable `count` somewhere else, it is `undefined` until you click `.metric` or `.imperial`.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer in it's current form. We need more context. Try to put this together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)–or even better [stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)–that reproduces the described behavior.

Comment: jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript functions written by other people. You pass data between functions the same way as usual.

Comment: jQuery is a library of javascript. They are not separate languages, so of course they can use each other's variables. In fact, they both use the same variable, not different.

Comment: Your modification is not even syntactically correct. Could you please not try to improvise anymore?

Comment: i fixed the snippet of code, also i meant from jquery to vanilla javascipt

Comment: jQuery is just a library. It **IS** vanilla JS.

Comment: You did not fix the snippet of code. After your edit it throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: dfsq - i want to track the count from one stage to the other stage??

Comment: What's `function (test){
   console.log(count);     
}` supposed to do?

Comment: Not sure where to start....

Comment: i want to see the variable be displayed once i click on the two buttons.

Comment: @AhmedHassan — Then you have to do something to display it **when you click a button**.

Comment: @Quentin- Currently getting undefined. Can you answer this question can you pass a variable from jQuery into javascript???

Comment: -*Facepalm*- jQuery **is** javascript, it's like a cheat sheet. People make functions to make it easier for others to use. So if you have a variable in jQuery you can access it using your own functions without the use of any jQuery.

Comment: @AhmedHassan - you would have to get in your head that jQuery is just a "helper (library)" to achieve things in javascript that otherwise are a lot harder to achieve!

Answer (score 3):

You are logging the value of `count` when the `script` element is parsed and executed for the first time. That is before the buttons have been clicked (and, since you have a `ready` handler in play, also before the event handlers have even been assigned), so it is also before you have given a value to `count`.

Since you haven't declared `count` at that stage, it shouldn't log it as having the value `undefined` but report an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined`.

If you want to see the new value after you have clicked a button, then you will have to log it to the console again after you have done that. (e.g. by putting a `console.log` call in each of your click event handler functions).

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is just a javascript-library so it is javascript. If you want to get (and set) the value of count globally, I would recommend you to define it as global so it's easier to read/have control of the code.

```
var count; //global

jQuery(function($){
    $( '.metric' ).click(function(){
        count = 0;
    });
    $( '.imperial' ).click(function(){
        count = 1;  
    });
});

function test() {
   console.log(count);     
}
```

If you run `test()` for the first time variable `count` would be undefined because it is not set until you've clicked on it (then set to 0 or 1)

Comment: As there was no `var count;` in the code given by the OP the `count` was global anyway.

Comment: @t.niese - ah. didn't really think of that - that's true even though I think its good to define it as global for better structure in code. I've updated my answer.

Comment: have a look at my new snippet of code, i just want the variable to be displayed on the console. Currently getting undefined.

Comment: Well best practice in the browser is not create any global variables, except one that is then used as a common namespace for all of the variables.

Comment: You get undefined because count isn't set at that stage. The console.log is executed once the javascript is loaded.

Comment: @t.niese - I agree, but if you have to define a global variable I believe you should tell the reader of the code that.

Comment: @AhmedHassan - make a new click-event handler and do a console.log of count and you would get your desired value.